# Save two or more different RDDs in a single text file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use `saveAsTextFile` like,

```
rdd1.saveAsTextFile("../savefile")
rdd2.saveAsTextFile("../savefile")
```

I can't put two different RDDs into a single text file. Is there a way I can do so?

Besides, is there a way I can apply some format to the text I am wring to the text file? For example, add a `\n` or some other format.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than just a union `(first ++ second).saveAsTextFile("../savefile")` "

Comment: So if i use `(rdd1 ++rdd2).saveAsTextFile`, I can save these two RDDs in the same file? And can I apply some format to these RDDs in the file?

Answer (score 1):

1. A *single text file* is rather ambiguous in Spark. Each partition is saved individually and it means you get a single file per partition. If you want a single for a RDD you have to move your data to a single partition or collect, and most of the time it is either to expensive or simply not feasible.
2. You can get an union of RDDs using `union` method (or `++` as mentioned by [lpiepiora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480975/lpiepiora) in the comments) but it works only if both RDDs are of the same type:

   ```
   val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
   val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
   rdd1.union(rdd2)

   // <console>:26: error: type mismatch;
   //  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
   //  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
   //               rdd1.union(rdd2)
   ```

   If types are different a whole idea smells fishy though.
3. [If you want a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202276/save-two-or-more-different-rdds-in-a-single-text-file-in-scala#comment54210039_33202276) you have to apply it before calling `saveAsTextFile`. `saveAsTextFile` simply [calls `toString`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f85aa06464a10f5d1563302fd76465dded475a12/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1415) on each element.

Putting all of the above together:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val rddStr1: RDD[String] = rdd1.map(x => ???) // Map to RDD[String]
val rddStr2: RDD[String] = rdd2.map(x => ???)

rdd1.union(rdd2)
  .repartition(1) // Not recommended!
  .saveAsTextFile(some_path)
```